# Replicate running paragraph summaries inset within paragraphs?

Tags: formatting, paragraphs, typography, parallel-texts

See the below example, from [the 1804 English edition of the Abbe Raynal's *History of the Two Indies*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Philosophical_and_Political_History_of/Qqw1AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). Please let me know if this has been asked or answered elsewhere --- by a package or otherwise. I just couldn't find any.
[image: inset section summaries]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to look at [`wrapfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{18ex}
\itshape Arrival of the Portuguefe in the Eaf Indies
\end{wrapfigure}
Emanuel purfued the plan marked out by his predeceffors. On the 18th  of July 1497, he fent out a fleet, confifting of four fhips, and gave the command of it to Vafco de Gama. This admiral, having weathered feveral ftorms in his cruife along the ealtern coafts of Africa, and attempted feas before unknown, landed at length in Indoftan, after a voyage of thirteen months.

\end{document}
```

[image]